# Install pyarrow in VS Code for Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyarrow

I am trying to install pyarrow v10.0.0 to a Python 3.11.0 project in both IntelliJ and VS Code. I am using v1.73.0 of VS Code on WIndows 11.

We use a custom JFrog instance to pull all the libraries. To pull the libraries we use the pip manager extension.

I have version 0.38.0 of wheel.

At the top of the output log is the following error message.

Using cached https://xxxjrog.com/artifactory/api/pypi/ENT_WDA_python_virtual/packages/packages/bd/3d/9594c09e1e2fe2e5ed7ef5c22e4347fee2ea243bccd960442e2c97731fd2/pyarrow-10.0.0.tar.gz (994 kB)
Installing build dependencies: started
Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.6 in c:\users\app1dwg\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pyarrow) (1.23.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build pyarrow

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

At the bottom of the output is the following error. I noticed it was using Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64", but I have upgraded to the most recent version of the MS build tools as was suggested in another post.

> -- Running CMake for PyArrow C++   cmake -DARROW_BUILD_DIR=build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\app1dwg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-399aazc6\pyarrow_6bd82e73181f4c8985e52c102dc8bb5e\build\dist
> -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\app1dwg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
> -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\app1dwg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
> -DPYARROW_CXXFLAGS= -DPYARROW_WITH_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_WITH_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARROW_WITH_HDFS=off -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
> C:\Users\app1dwg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-399aazc6\pyarrow_6bd82e73181f4c8985e52c102dc8bb5e\pyarrow/src   error: command 'cmake' failed: None
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
>
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to
> install pyproject.toml-based projects

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Python version **below** 3.11.0. According to the content mentioned in [github](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/14499), the package **pyarrow** does not support **Python version 3.11.0** at present

Comment: I reverted back to 3.10.0 and was able to get the package installed.